# Can any one explain me the behaviours of this keyword

Tags: javascript, jquery, element, this

I'm little bit confused about the behaviours of `this` keyword. I was trying to call a function when a button was clicked. But as I know when I call function `on click of an element the this should refer to the element` and it should return that element when we console. but in my case it is returning `[object HTMLInputElement]`.

code :

```
var self=this,submitAns=$('#submitAns');
submitAns.on('click',self.verifyAns);

    verifyAns:function(e){
        console.log('from verifyAns : '+this);
         e.preventDefault();
    }
```

The result from the console is `[object HTMLInputElement]`.

can anyone explain why, and how can I get the element.

Comment: Try console.log(this);  ONLY (this) - no string concatanation with +

Comment: @Mr.TK, it returns the element. Can you tell me why it won't return if we concatenate it with string.

Comment: Sorry :D No idea. I'm curious myself. :) I bet "+" it's overloaded to return HTMLInputElement while getting string and an element as arguments :) Javascript does not support overloading but the creators could done it them selfs. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` indeed refer's to the element. You can do some operations on that element using `this` like -

```
$(this).addClass('something');
$(this).html('something');
$(this).val('something'); // if it is a form element
console.log(this.id); // prints id of clicked element
```

Comment: Why I got that output is I concatenated `this` with `string`. Thanks all for your support.

Answer (score 0):

When a function is created, a keyword called `this` is created (behind the scenes),
which links to the object in which the function operates. Said another way, this is
available to the scope of its function, yet is a reference to the object of which that
function is a property or method.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><body><script>
var cody = {
living: true,
age: 23,
gender: 'male',
getGender: function () { return cody.gender; }
};
console.log(cody.getGender()); // Logs 'male'.
</script></body></html>
```

Notice how inside of the `getGender` function, we are accessing the gender property
using dot notation (e.g., `cody.gender`) on the cody object itself. This can be rewritten
using `this` to access the cody object because `this` points to the cody object.

Your correct code will be like this.

```
var submitAns=$('#submitAns');
submitAns.on('click', function verifyAns(e){
        console.log('from verifyAns : '+ $(this));
         e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: I think you are wrong when we are outside of the cody object how `this` will refers to `cody`. It should refer to the `dom` right?

Comment: `submitAns.on('click', verifyAns);` statement is absolutely wrong. I don't know how you refer to that function.

Comment: @james `verifyAns` is a function, it is perfectly legal to use it as event handler in `.on(event,handler)`

Comment: @Mohammad Adil you are right. But as I commented above, the function should follow the `object` it resides right?

Answer (score 0):

Actually "this" refers to the function where it's used, it doesn't represent the element, so if you have two function and in both you are using "this" then first "this will represent the first function and second "this" will represent the second function. If you want to call something else then you need to create object of that function/element and then you can call them.

You may find a better answer here:

[Understanding the Basic Concept of "this" Keyword](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/advance-javascript-be-master-in-this-keyword/)

Answer (score 0):

It's an HTML object, you can `stringify` it for your current output:

```
console.log('from verifyAns : '+JSON.stringify(this));
```

Or output it directly to the console as, you will then be able to see the entire block of HTML code:

```
console.log(this);
```

Comment: At present I'm getting `[object HTMLInputElement].` output for `console.log('from verifyAns : '+this);`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your input element as an object in then use this

```
console.log(this);
```

instead of

```
console.log('from verifyAns : '+this);
```